# How to make CSS based on different phone screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

im trying to style the page based on different phone sizes. I know that I can use media queries, but what if the width of the phone is the same, but height is different. For instance, both Iphone X and 6,7,8 has the same width, but different length

Comment: Then you'd query for the height as opposed to the width.

Comment: with max-length?

Comment: This question seems very broad. It's more like a design decision to whether set a set height, min/max, or auto.

Comment: No. It would be `max-height` in this case.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what Carl said in his comment.

The following is a valid example:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that you should use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) (as already mentioned).
Not only can you change stylistics according to screen `max-width` and `max-height`, but also to `orientation: portrait` and even `aspect-ratio:`.

---

Apart from that I think you could make css rules around the concept of [relative units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).
You can make whole content scalable
 - not just
`div { width: 20vw; }`

but also
`p { font-size: 5vmin; }`
That way you won't need to worry about weird aspect ratios or different resolutions.